# Capybara + Selenium 2.0 sometimes fails to click on anchor tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, selenium-webdriver

It fails to click on anchor tag <a href="#" onclick="...some js function...;return false;"> (I know <a href="#"> is a bad practice.)

I found some answer on the internet to use fireEvent. But Selenium2.0 does not provide that function anymore, nor Capybara.

Anybody encounters the same problem?

(Now I'm trying Watir-WebDriver, which does not seem to have this problem so far. It is somewhat strange because in watir-webdriver, it uses selenium-webdriver :S)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a custom step like the one below and invoke it..

```
When /^(?:|I )follow javascript anchor "([^"]*)"$/ do |link_selector|
   page.execute_script("$('#{link_selector}').click()")
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it.
Anyway, I have found the root of the problem. It is because of CSS.

Please see my blog post: http://whowish-programming.blogspot.com/2011/09/selenium-sometimes-does-not-click-on.html

Comment: I have tried the javascript solution. It works with <a .. onclick ...>. However, it does not work with a normal anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of click, use SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter)